# getting net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED error on production

Tags: nginx, server, localhost, connection-refused

I have deployed my react app which also has a backend. I have started both my front end and backend from my server using npm start command. The front end is working correctly but the backend is not. (Works perfectly from localhost)

The frontend is open from port 3000 and backend from port 9000.

This is my nginx config

```
    server {
       server_name myservername.com www.myservername.com;
       location / {
         proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
         proxy_http_version 1.1;
         proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
         proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";  
       }
    }

server {
   if($host = www.myservername.com){
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
   if($host = myservername.com){
     return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
   }
   listen 80 default_server;
   listen [::]:80 default_server;

   server_name myservername.com www.myservername.com;

   return 404;

}
```

ports that are in use

[image]

The error i'm getting in console

```
POST http://localhost:9000/bot net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
```

How can i fix this issue?

The issue is trying to do this fetch

```
fetch("http://localhost:9000/bot", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => {
          res = JSON.parse(res);
          this.setState({ apiResponse: res.response, apiIntent: res.intent}, () => {this.setBotMsg()}); 
          console.log(`This is the response: ${res.response}, ${res.intent}`); 
          ;
        });
```

Comment: looks like you are not proxying any traffic for port 9000 through nginx. How do you send the POST request? Curl? Or what console do you mean? Does the service listen on port 9000? Are you able to use `telnet` to see if the connection is open? `telnet localhost 9000`.

Comment: Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'

--> this is what i get with that command

Comment: @TimoStark i meant the browser console. POST request is updated in the question.

Comment: Okay so your main problem is that you are trying to connect to `localhost:9000` from your browser. For your browser `localhost:9000` is your computer. In case the backend is running on the server AND port 9000 is exposed you have to use `myservername.com:9000` instead of localhost. Or use nginx to proxy port 9000 with a new location or subdomain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will issue a call to your local loopback adapter on your computer port 9000. I don't think this is what you want. Use your server IP or domainname inseat of localhost.

```
fetch("http://myservername.com:9000/bot", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => {
          res = JSON.parse(res);
          this.setState({ apiResponse: res.response, apiIntent: res.intent}, () => {this.setBotMsg()}); 
          console.log(`This is the response: ${res.response}, ${res.intent}`); 
          ;
        });
```

I would use NGINX to proxy the request to your backend and not expose port 9000 directly.

```
fetch("https://myservername.com/bot", {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        body: JSON.stringify(data)
      }).then(res => res.text())
        .then(res => {
          res = JSON.parse(res);
          this.setState({ apiResponse: res.response, apiIntent: res.intent}, () => {this.setBotMsg()}); 
          console.log(`This is the response: ${res.response}, ${res.intent}`); 
          ;
        });
```

The nginx configuration depends on what you are want to do. Subdomain or location? A subdomain could be something like `bot.myserver.com`. A location `myserver.com/bot`.

```
server {
 listen 443


  .....


  location /bot {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    ....
  }

}
```

Additional note: I have updated the configuration to use https from the frontend.

Comment: Thanks! I have created a sub domain to my api and pointed my backend to there. Now it works!